Plupload version 2.3.9 does not stop upload correctly on file remove
When removing a file during upload process the file is removed from queue and destroyed and also the uploader progress stops correctly. But the FileUploader/ChunkUploader is continuing in the background (file does not appear in the queue anymore) so if you add a new file to the upload queue the upload waits until the Fileuploader has finished the upload of the removed file.
Could not find a possibility to access/destroy the Fileuploader.
Only solution that works for me are changes in the main code to check in the FileUploader if file was already destroyed,
Is there another solution without touching the main code?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
